# Regex, replace almost all punctuation

Tags: java, regex, replace

How can I add to the replaceAll regex that I do not want to change hyphen(-) either (so every punctuation except - and ')?

```
long l = Arrays.stream(words ).map(n -> n.replaceAll("(?!')\\p{Punct}","")).map(String::toLowerCase).distinct().count();
```

Comment: I think you want a character class ``(?!['-])\p{Punct}``